# How can I get the instance of an application?

Tags: android

I want to display the log details of my application.How can I get the instance of my application so that I can diplay the log of my application only?

Comment: I didn't understand. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I just want the reference to my application so that i can filter all the logs related to my app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there's no way you can do that.

Here are a couple of alternatives....

1) Add a Special identifier to each log entry, use the Filter feature of the DDMS Logcat to filter out just your Log Entries.

2) Make a Custom `Log` that writes to a file (which you can later pull.)

3) I've never tried this myself, but i wonder if one could make a TCP Server, to which we could connect (using telnet) and retrieve the log details...Hmmm, Nice pet project idea! *lightbulb

Cheers!